# ASP.NET MVC count elements in a database

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 2 models `Car`s and `Brand`s and they are related by one car having one brand but a brand can be in different cars. Now I need to list the count of how many cars are in one brand

```
@Html.DisplayText(item.Cars.Where(p=>p.BrandID==item.ID).Count().ToString())
```

I have tried this and some other things that look like it with the count but nothing works and even tried some counts in the Controller but it would only get me the count for one of the brands

Comment: `but nothing works` what was the error or wrong value you are getting ?

Comment: Share your code in the controller or which populates `item`.

Comment: like Hadi said include your code, so we can see what you are doing.. At the display level is to late we , need to see all relevant code. for example item is what, we cant tell as we can see the code. its easier to just post the code needed.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a count of `Car`s that belong to a particular `Brand` You are good with only:

```
item.Cars.Count().ToString()
```

since `item` is an already associated with its `Car`s.